# File .avro empty when uploaded to GCP Bucket

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, google-cloud-platform, avro, bucket

I'm creating a function that uses multhreading to upload .avro files to a bucket.
Some files go with data but others go empty, although I had made a filter to ignore this type of files and when I test locally all files are saved with data in my computer's directory.

Here's my code:

```
    def save_file(self, data: dict, filename: str):
        """
            Converte e Salva Arquivo no formato .avra para o Google Cloud Storage
        """
        try:
            if not data or not any(data.values()):
                logger.warning(
                    "Os dados do arquivo %s estão vazios. O arquivo não será salvo.", filename)
                return False
            
            with self.threading_lock:
                avro_schema = dumps({
                        "namespace": "avro_schema.avro",
                        "type": "record",
                        "name": "data",
                        "fields": [
                            {"name": "url", "type": "string"}
 
                        ]
                    })
                schema = avro.schema.parse(avro_schema)
                archive = BytesIO()

                writer = DataFileWriter(archive, DatumWriter(), schema)
                writer.append(data)

                archive.seek(0)
                archive_bytes = archive.getvalue()
                blob = self.bucket.blob(filename)
                # blob.upload_from_file(archive)
                blob.upload_from_string(archive_bytes)
                writer.close()

                return True
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("excecao ao salvar: %s , %s", filename, str(e))
            return False
```

I have already tryed to use threading.lock() and apply a filter for empty datas.